# How can I express alternative dependencies in NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, alternate

When expressing the dependencies of a Debian package, you can use syntax like `exim | mail-transport-agent` to indicate that your package needs *either* `exim` or `mail-transport-agent`, but it doesn't care which.

I want to express something similar in NPM. Is there a way to do it? Specifically suppose I want my application to express a dependency on *either* `mikesthing-impl1` v1.7 better *or* `mikesthing-impl2` v2.1 or better. I'd like to be able to say something like:

```
dependencies: {
  "mikesthing": {
    "mikesthing-impl1": "^1.7",
    "mikesthing-impl2": "^2.1"
  }
}
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no functionality within a package.json to specify that sort of logic.  However, you can implement a `postinstall` script in the `scripts` that will be executed after all other dependencies have been installed and in which you can script out this kind (or any kind) of behavior.

e.g. (in `package.json`)

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "./bin/postinstall"
```

A good place to start is to run `npm view {package}` to get back a JSON object that details what versions are available in the registry.

Comment: Thanks for this bad news -- hey, it's better to know, right?

Unfortunately, a postinstall script won't get me what I want in this case. I could write a script that rejects the present package's installation unless at least one of the alternative dependencies is in place, but that would be a procedural implementation. What I need is a declaration -- something that other code can look at and understand.

Oh well. You can't always get what you want.